# Resize a table cell

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to resize the first cell. I'm trying with max-widh, and put the style in the HTML and with width, but I can't resize that cell.
Is a table with sticky row and col

This is de css code.

```css
div {
  max-width: 40em;
  max-height: 30em;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

table {
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 0.30em;
}

thead th {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  color: #000;
  
  
}

thead th:first-child {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  
}

tbody th {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background: #FFF;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div>
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>head </th>
                  <th>head</th>
                  <th>head</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th>Closer2Nature Shopify UK</th>
                  <td>body</td>
                  <td>body</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
```

This is the HTML code for the table with a sticky col and row.

Comment: Can you share the HTML code as well

Comment: Of course mate.

Comment: you got your answer or you still looking for it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand, why not use only `width`?

```
thead th:first-child {
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I've tried width and it doesn't work for me. I've also tried different kinds of measurements.

Comment: This didn't work in my code. It must be another problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly this is what you need?

```css
#MainDiv {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 310px;
}

table {
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 0.30em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

thead th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  color: #000;
  background-color: gray;
}

thead th:first-child {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

tbody th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background: #FFF;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div id="MainDiv">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>head </th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Closer2Nature Shopify UK</th>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Closer2Nature Shopify UK</th>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Closer2Nature Shopify UK</th>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Closer2Nature Shopify UK</th>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Closer2Nature Shopify UK Closer2Nature Shopify UK</th>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Closer2Nature Shopify UK</th>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Closer2Nature Shopify UK</th>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: If that's it but I need to modify the width of the first col. And I can't

Comment: How you want to modify the width? is it dynamically or using css?